# Добавить в заголовок Графика значение переменной

Tags: юнит-тесты, test-automation, jmeter

Вопрос по `JMeter` - как в `Title` графика `Agregate Graph` добавить значение переменной ?

[image: Agregate Graph]

В данный момент вместо значения на графике прописывается просто текст, как изменить что бы заголовок был `Aggregate 1000` ?